# Gerar chaves de confronto entre times utilizando um array em PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Opa!!

Tenho o seguinte array em **php**, preciso criar um confronto entre os times sendo que os times que forem do mesmo grupo/array exemplo Time 01 e Time 02 não podem se enfrentar na primeira rodada.

Pensei em verificar se o elemento são do mesmo array se sim pega um e passa para o próximo, só que não consegui fazer essa verificação. Não sei se já existe uma função que faça isso!!

Se alguém tiver uma dica de como fazer fico grato!!

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Time 01"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Time 02"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Time 03"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Time 04"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem você quer definir **todas** as partidas **sem repetição** entre times de grupos **diferentes**.

Esse pareamento pode ser obtido fazendo com que um loop percorra todos os times desde o início `($i=1,...,n)` e um segundo loop que percorra todos os times a partir do primeiro loop em diante `($j=$i,...,n)`.

Eu recomendo você tentar fazer, pois é uma tarefa simples e, somente se não der, olhar a solução a seguir:

```
$grupo1 = array("Time 01","Time 02");
$grupo2 = array("Time 03");
$grupo3 = array("Time 04");
$array_grupos = array($grupo1,$grupo2,$grupo3);
$n_de_grupos = count($array_grupos);    


$jogos= array();
for($i=0;$i<$n_de_grupos;$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$n_de_grupos;$j++){
        $grupoA = $array_grupos[$i];
        $grupoB = $array_grupos[$j];

        foreach($grupoA as $timeA){
            foreach($grupoB as $timeB){
                echo $timeA.$timeB.'<br>'; //imprime na tela 
                $jogos[]=array($timeA,$timeB);  //ou armazena em vetor
            }
        }
    }
}

//saída do echo:
Time 01Time 03
Time 02Time 03
Time 01Time 04
Time 02Time 04
Time 03Time 04
```

Comment: Opa!!

Obrigado por responder!! Mas na verdade é o contrário os times do mesmo grupo **(indice do array)** não podem se enfrentar na primeira rodada!! 

Mas pelo seu exemplo vou tentar fazer aqui!!

Comment: Bem, no meu exemplo os times de um mesmo grupo não se enfrentam, o contrário seria se só membros do mesmo grupo se enfrentassem...de todo modo, se serviu pra te guiar tá valendo.